# iMac 21.5-inch Mid 2010 won't boot into OS X after installing Ubuntu, will boot into grub rescue

Tags: macos, imac, bootcamp, unix

So, as the title says, I have an iMac 21.5-inch Mid 2010 model and I installed Windows 8.1 with Boot Camp. After attempting to uninstall Ubuntu and Windows in Disk Utility (in OS X and Recovery) it would always give me an error,
"Partition failed with the error:
The requested size change for the target disk or a related disk is too small. Please try a different disk or partition, or make a larger change."

**What I have tried:**

1. I have tried resetting PRAM/NVRAM with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, nothing.
2. I have tried holding <kbd>X</kbd> to Start up from an OS X startup volume when the Mac would otherwise start up from a non-OS X startup volume. Using [Startup key combinations for Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255), still nothing (did work before).
3. I have done things in grub rescue such as `ls (lists partitions and disks)` and attempted to boot back into Ubuntu.
4. I have tried holding <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> to get into the startup manager, still boots to grub rescue.
5. I have tried holding <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to boot into Recovery, worked before, not working now.

**What I can't do:**

- Can't use another Mac to do anything such as target disk mode (no firewire cable).

**My iMac Specs:**

[iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2010) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP588?locale=en_US)

21.5 inch, 3.06 Mhz, has OSX 10.10 installed with Windows and Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Also, I can't hear startup chimes, so I might not be able to clear the NVRAM/PRAM correctly.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 14 installed along with OS X 10.10.4 and Windows 8.1 on my mid 2007 20 inch iMac. You have not yet asked a question. Do you have one? BTW, you probably erased both OS X and the Recovery partitions. Did your model come with an OS X installation DVD? In not, then did you create a Recovery Mode USB flash drive? You can try booting using Command-Option-R, but your model might be to old to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed after many days. I noticed that the keyboard wasn't initializing during boot so I picked up a new keyboard(something I didn't even think of at the time) and it initialized. I held the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and to prevent this from happening again I installed rEFInd.